# Word that means "full attendance"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to ask whether we're waiting for full attendance before convening, ex: 'waiting [to hold the meeting] until we're quorate', but 'quorate' (as I understand it) only implies 'enough people to hold the meeting' whereas I want to communicate 'everyone who is eligible to attend is present'.

ex:

> '... waiting [to hold the meeting] until we're _______ [quorate?]'

Comment: Not an adjective, so not an answer.. but a 'full complement' would refer to everyone eligible, in this context. For example: 'Are we waiting for the full complement before holding the meeting?'

Comment: Why be fancy? Why not just say "... until we're all here" or "... everybody's here"?

Comment: Except *quorate* is BrE.

Comment: The deleted answer 'we have a full house' and the 1960s noun phrase SRO ('It was SRO at the Adelphi') are informal possibilities.

Comment: Quorate is often used informally to mean "we have everyone who should be here" or "everyone we need". Since most meetings don't have a formal quorum defined, it should be unambiguous unless you're in the US Senate or parish council or something like that.

Comment: Comprehension of the word "quorate" in American English would be near nil, and honestly, I've never heard it used in British English either, so it is probably limited to some specific speech register of British English and not in general usage in that dialect either.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 'until we are **complete**'.

> Having all its parts or members; comprising the full number or amount; embracing all the requisite items, details, topics, etc.; entire, full.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/37656?rskey=liRWA4&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)

Comment: The only thing wrong with this suggestion is that it's not commonly used in the sense required, of a meeting which everyone attends.  If I read or heard the expression *we are complete* I might think it was someone spouting new-age psychobabble about the state of their relationship(s).  And if you told me that the meeting was complete, my first thought would be that it had finished with all agenda items addressed.  Meh.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  The Chairperson said, as the last member arrived, 'We are complete, let us begin'. At the end it would be ungrammatical to say that and also unidiomatic to say 'we are completed'. They would say 'We are finished ; let us adjourn.'

Comment: Please, Nigel, don't do any such thing. That dictionary definition of "complete" wouldn't make it relevant, let alone useful.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Colloquial language, as it develops, often departs from 'dictionary definition'. That's the beauty (and flexibility) of the spoken word.

Comment: @NigelJ Sadly, your mistrust of dictionaries lends no credence to your Chair saying, as the last member arrived, 'We are complete, let us begin'

"At the end" might sometimes not be ungrammatical; it would always be unidiomatic.

"We are complete" would always be un-either; always both ungrammatical and  un-idiomatic.

If "We are completed…" was something like what you wanted to express, you would need either "We are completed by…" or "We have been completed (by)…"

Do you really want to go into the differences among the Question, completion and "We are finished…"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin You have just proved my point by stating 'un-either'. The word is 'neither' but I like your non-dictionary word (I just checked OED and it is not there) and I shall use it at the first opportunity and I shall remember you when I do so. Together, we shall make it 'idiomatic' by using it. Regards :)

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks. I prolly wouldn't have done that if I'd thought about it but my fingers ran away with themselves and seemed to be doing well enough on their own.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider “plenum”. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plenum

Def: An assembly of all the members of a group or committee.

‘the seventh plenum of the Communist Party central committee’

Comment: Plenum (a plenary session) is a meeting that is *supposed* to be attended by all the members of some formal body (in contrast to e.g. a meeting of its (sub)committee devoted to a particular topic), regardless of whether it is in fact attended by all of them. The OP is, however, seeking a term for a meeting being *in fact* attended by all who are supposed to attend it (regardless of whether those who are supposed to attend it are all members of the relevant body or only a subgroup of it).

Answer (score -2):

You could try to use "entire" or "whole". I feel that "whole" is not a great word for this because it could have additional implications which you possibly want to avoid.

**Entire**

> Having no element or part left out

**Whole**

> Having all its proper parts or components

Both of these definitions were taken from [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/)